# Why checkbox isn't work as expected with inline edit - Kendo Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, kendo-grid

I've a Kendo Grid in my application, I use ClientTemplate for checkbox in a column. The checkbox isn't display when the page loads, but the property(CheckName) value is true, so it should be. Another thing is, when I click to the checkbox, and after that click on another, the previous checked checkbox dissapears. I use InCell edit, maybe it cause the problem? Any advice'd be helpful.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<myViewModel>()
    .Name("mygrid")
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CheckName)
                .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= CheckName ? checked='checked' : '' # onclick='setCheckName()' id='CheckNameid' />")

        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
    })
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .Read(r => r.Action("ReadData", "MyContr"))
        .Update(u => u.Action("UpdateData", "MyContr"))
        .AutoSync(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(m => m.Id);
            model.Field(m => m.CheckName);
            model.Field(m => m.Name);
        })
    )
)

function setCheckName() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("setCheckName")"
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            CheckName: $('#CheckNameId').is(':checked'),
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you mention contents inside `setCheckName()` function? The expected behavior is still unclear, explain in sample images if you can and provide more details to current code.

Comment: There're more rows, in every row there's a checkbox. When I click on it, after click on another row's checkbox, the previous dissapears.